# Retrofit call.enqueue code 200, but response.body() is empty

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I have a problem with getting `JSON` from `response.body()` from my **API**.

Logcat is showing that request is successful, but when I want to copy the body to my model object, then it is null.

I already shortened the `JSON` only to one key and value (end of logcat), but even then I cant read the response.

**Logcat:**

```
D/OkHttp: <-- 200  http://10.0.2.2:8080/groups?page=1&limit=25 (33ms)    
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 14 Jan 2019 19:31:10 GMT
D/OkHttp: [{"name":"Delfiny"}]
<-- END HTTP (20-byte body)
```

**Model class:**

```
public class GroupsResponseModel {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

public GroupsResponseModel() {
}

public GroupsResponseModel(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

**ApiInterface:**

```
@GET("groups")
Call<GroupsResponseModel> getGroups(@Query("page") int page, 
@Query("limit") int limit);
```

**Retrofit and Interceptor:**

```
public static Retrofit getClient()
{
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new 
HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().
            addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws 
IOException {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();

            Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder().header(Utils.getAuthKey(),
                    Utils.getAuthValue());

            Request newRequest = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    })
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Utils.getURL())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    return retrofit;
}
```

**Call enqueue:**

```
Call<GroupsResponseModel> call = apiInterface.getGroups(1, 25);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<GroupsResponseModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GroupsResponseModel> call, Response<GroupsResponseModel> response) {

                     groupsResponseModel = response.body();

                    Toast.makeText(GroupActivity.this, "response: " + groupsResponseModel.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //groups = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(groupsResponseModel.getName()));
                    groupAdapter = new GroupAdapter(groups);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(groupAdapter);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GroupsResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

Expected result needs to be parsed.

Comment: What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: I was checking debugger for 2 hours and I couldnt find the issue. I finally set the breakpoint on the correct function (call.enqueue(new Callback<GroupsResponseModel>())  - it was not returning code 200, but a Failure that class cant be loaded. Topic can be closed.

Comment: Are you loading a list of groups (List<GroupsResponseModel>), or are you expecting only one GroupsResponseModel? If you are expecting a list as a result, the return type of your getGroups() method should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely sure that server sends proper json - check your pojo class. Start with deleting @Exposed annotation

Comment: Server send the List of GroupRest objects:

public class GroupRest {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you that use  Android Studio debugging tools like  Profiler to monitoring network (api calls) requests & responses body,  that easily accessible on Network section of profiler, take a look at this link:[Profiler Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler)